# geom_text in Choropleth map (ggplot2)

Tags: r, google-maps, csv

I'm working with choropleth map (ggplot2), i have problem implementing geom_text properly. In output it is showing text over map but i can see many repeated name, no idea why, and need help to fix that please. Using R studio, Australia map shape file and data in a csv file. Moreover I had intention to show values over map instead of state names, don't know how.

## codes in UI.R file

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(fluidPage( 

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Unemployment rate Data"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the variable to plot against
  # specify whether outliers should be included
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Type:", 
                  c("States" = "region",
                    "Unemployment_Rate" = "unemployment_rate_2015"
                                    )
      )

      #checkboxInput("outliers", "Show outliers", FALSE)
    ),

    # Show the caption and plot of the requested variable against population     data data
    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption")),
      plotOutput("datPlot")
    )
  )#----/sidebar layout
))#----/shinyUI
```

## codes in Server.R file

```
require(maptools)
require(ggmap)
require(maps)
require(mapproj)
require(data.table)
library(rgeos)
library(plyr)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)


library(ggplot2) # load ggplot
setwd("C:/Users/AbdullahAl/Documents/AU-Shapefile")
pop <- read.csv("unemployment.csv") 
AUS = readShapeSpatial("AUS_adm1")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # Compute the forumla text in a reactive expression since it is 
  # shared by the output$caption and output$mpgPlot expressions
  output$caption <- reactiveText(function(){
    paste("States ~", input$variable)
  })

  # ggplot version
  output$datPlot <- reactivePlot(function() {
    pop <- data.table(States = pop$region, var =  factor(pop[[input$variable]]))

    # Generate a plot of the requested variable against year and only 
    # include outliers if requested
    AUS <- fortify(AUS, region = "NAME_1")
    #add color="black" inside geom_map to have the boarder black
      ggplot() + geom_map(data = pop, aes(map_id = States, fill = var), map = AUS) + 
         expand_limits(x = AUS$long, y = AUS$lat) +

      # to add values over 
    geom_text(data = AUS, aes(x =long , y = lat, label = id, size = 2.5),
               check_overlap = TRUE, position = "jitter", parse = FALSE) +
    geom_label()    
    # facet_wrap( ~ var) - use this to show each divided states

  })
})
```

Link for .csv file 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=15945AE760E741A4!2712&authkey=!AChRc_Cl_PjJ_I4&ithint=file%2ccsv

And the output as image
[the image is showing Australis's map and repeated name of the states over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQAY5.png)